# asyncjs - eachSeries() doesn't iterate through all items in array

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have the following code which uses async.js

```
var async = require('async');
var A = [];

for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    A.push(i);

async.eachSeries(A, function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

I expected this to print numbers from 1 to 100, however when I run this the output is just `1`

If I use `each()` instead of `eachSeries()` it prints all the numbers, though.

So, why is the code not working while `eachSeries()` is just a serial version of `each()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iterator functions needs 2 arguments `item` and `callback`, `callback` must be called once the iteration is complete.

```
async.eachSeries(A, function(item, callback) {
    console.log(item);
    callback();
});
```

Comment: I think callbacks are optional. Also, if this is the problem it shouldn't work with `each()` because `each()` takes the same arguments as `eachSeries()`

Comment: From the documentation: `iterator(item, callback) - A function to apply to each item in the array. The iterator is passed a callback(err) which must be called once it has completed. If no error has occured, the callback should be run without arguments or with an explicit null argument.`

Comment: But then the `eachSeries()` also takes a callback function as argument, right? So, why is that not needed?

Comment: Because you might want to ignore if an iteration raised an error or if all the functions finished.

Comment: I don't get it. Can't I use the same reasoning for not using the first callback(). Also, why does same set of arguments work work with `each()` and not with `eachSeries()`. 
Just because it is parallel should make no difference since both have the same format.

Comment: In `each` every iterator gets called because of the parallelism, in `eachSeries`, as you can read from the docs, **The next iterator is only called once the current one has completed processing. This means the iterator functions will complete in order**. It just the way it is implemented.